# How to run Powershell from the Windows Explorer Address Bar

Tags: windows, powershell, explorer

When I run 'Powershell' from the Windows Address bar it opens up the Powershell command prompt and is open at the folder that's being browsed to. The problem is that it's version 5 of Powershell.
How do I get it to open the latest version of Powershell on my PC (Powershell 7) from the address bar?

I'm using Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: By typing the appropriate executable name: `pwsh`

Comment: Or by typing `wt` for Windows Terminal, if that's what you're normally using for PowerShell 7.

Comment: See also: [about_Pwsh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows PowerShell is `powershell.exe`
PowerShell is `pwsh.exe`